# Unknown error on Arduino in blinking light code

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-c++

I'm trying to create this project so a light blinks constantly and then it prints the milliseconds with the following *New wait time: 100*(for example)

```
const int ledPin = 13;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {

  static int delayPeriod = 100;

  int countDir = 1;

  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);

  delay(delayPeriod);

  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);

  delay(delayPeriod);

  countDir = checkDirChange(delayPeriod, countDir);

  Serial.println("New wait time: ");
  Serial.print(delayPeriod);

  delayPeriod += 100 * countDir;
}

int checkDirChange(int delayPeriod, int countDir) {

  if ((delayPeriod == 100) || (delayPeriod == 0)) {

    countDir *= -1;

    if (countDir < 0) {
      Serial.println("Going down.");
    } else {
      Serial.println("Succesful");
    } 

    return countDir;
  }
}
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question nor clearly explained what specific problem you have. What does "unknown error" mean? What exact error or incorrect behaviour are you encountering?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are NOT asking a question. What is the exact problem you are facing?

Second, your logic doesn't make sense. You are creating negative values and assigning them as delays which is evidently incorrect. What are you trying to achieve with it?

This:

> `delayPeriod += 100 * countDir;`

will become negative after the second iteration. After this, the code will behave erratically.

This is a quick and *dirty* test of your code in Codelite (where I just emulated the delays by system pauses and also emulated the *loop()* using a short *while* loop):

[image: Arduino code emualted in Codelite]

Please clarify the purpose of your code.

I highly encourage you to use the  `millis()` function as a proper approach for timing events. Please refer to [this](https://learn.adafruit.com/multi-tasking-the-arduino-part-1/using-millis-for-timing) guide

P.S. Yeah, I promise I will activate my Windows *very* soon ;)